# can not exclude files from input in doxygen

Tags: c++, doxygen

I want to generate a file list with `gcc -M` which delivers something like the following which works fine:

```
../active_var/timervar.h \
../active_var/universal_var.h \
../chrono_timer/chrono_timer.cpp \
/home/bla/foreign_components/gmock-1.7.0/fused-src/gmock/gmock.h \
/home/bla/foreign_components/gmock-1.7.0/fused-src/gmock-gtest-all.cc \
/home/bla/foreign_components/gmock-1.7.0/fused-src/gmock_main.cc \
/home/bla/foreign_components/gmock-1.7.0/fused-src/gtest/gtest.h \
../../mtp/index_tuple.h \
../observer/observer_with_stop_marker.h \
test_bugfixing.cpp \
test_counter.cpp \
```

I give this files to the

```
INPUT = <files as listed above >
```

This works as expected.

Now I simply want to ignore the files coming from `/home/bla/foreign_components/`

I tried:

```
EXCLUDE = */home/bla/foreign_components/*
```

or

```
EXCLUDE = /home/bla/foreign_components/
```

or

```
EXCLUDE = /home/bla/foreign_components/*
```

nothing works!

I tried the same with all above listed patterns with the `EXCLUDE_PATTERNS`

Also no effect.

Is this feature simply broken in `doxygen` or can files which are explicitly listed in files not be filtered out?

I am using doxygen version: `1.8.10`

Answer (score 1):

> can files which are explicitly listed in files not be filtered out?

I think so.

You can generate your `INPUT` list by filtering `gcc -M` output:

```
gcc -M | grep -v "/home/bla/foreign_components"
```